Using the Measure instead of the new column and calculating row by row in dax power bi
I need to analyze the sensitivity of the Wage,
I need to use measure instead of column to calculate row by row .
For a complete explanation, I have sent a PDF and all the items in it are mentioned.

Thank you for explaining if this is possible or not?
I emphasize again, I don't want to use the new column and I definitely need a measure .

It's easy to do, but you need to describe your data model better, because it's unclear what "value" is and how it's related to the other data in your table.

tanks. my data is flat excel .
There is only one table.

Using "Data" as your table name:
Wage = SUMX ( Data, IF ( Data[value] > 15000, 200, 100 ) )

How it works:

To force a measure to calculate row by row, you need to use "iterator" functions, like SUMX, AVERAGEX, etc.
SUMX essentially is a loop: it goes record by record in the data table, tests the IF statements, and produces results by row. Then the results are summed up.

